# Invoices not populated in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

In Netsuite : when I go to transactions-->customers -->Accept Customer payments.

I enter a customer name from the list for whom there are pending dues.

In the Subtab Apply-->Invoices.
In the Invoices section the pending invoices dont get populated for the corresponding customer.

What can be the possible reason.

How can i fix this permanantly.

Thanks in advance.

Gladiator

Comment: *Note : All the corresponding information is being eneterd for the account like A/R account, Payment Method, Posting Period. Still there are no invoices populated.

Answer (score 0):

When you do that the customers in that list are not filtered by only those who have open invoices. Any customer can show up there. If you want to streamline your payment application process you could start with a customer saved search filtered to those customers who have a balance. (Or an overdue balance).

If you have selected a customer who you think should have an open invoice you might want to analyze the situation by checking the status of that customer's invoices. Chances are they are all paid or have been re-assigned to a parent customer.